# Draw line between two gameObjects on UI Canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I want to draw a line between 2 gameObjects on a UI canvas.

After seeing it work in the sample from the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html) I started to implement my own. After playing around with some values in the gizmos I ventured forward to the OnPopulateMesh method to see it for real, but eventhough the Gizmos show exactly what I want, I saw nothing.

[image: The line shown with Gizmos]

I played around with the order of the vertex indexes in the AddTriangle method, but that did nothing.

```cs
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class UILineRenderer : Graphic
{
    public Vector3 BeginPoint;
    public float BeginOffset;
    public Vector3 EndPoint;
    public float EndOffset;
    public float Thickness;

    protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
    {
        var delta = EndPoint - BeginPoint;
        var perpendicularToUI = Vector3.Cross(delta, Vector3.forward);
        var thicknessVector = perpendicularToUI.normalized * (Thickness / 2f);

        var beginOrigin = BeginPoint + (delta.normalized * BeginOffset);
        var endOrigin = EndPoint - (delta.normalized * EndOffset);

        vh.Clear();

        UIVertex vertex = UIVertex.simpleVert;
        vertex.color = color;

        vertex.position = beginOrigin + thicknessVector;
        vh.AddVert(vertex);
        
        vertex.position = beginOrigin - thicknessVector;
        vh.AddVert(vertex);
        
        vertex.position = endOrigin + thicknessVector;
        vh.AddVert(vertex);

        vertex.position = endOrigin - thicknessVector;
        vh.AddVert(vertex);

        vh.AddTriangle(0, 1, 2);
        vh.AddTriangle(2, 3, 0);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(BeginPoint, EndPoint);

        var delta = EndPoint - BeginPoint;
        var perpen = Vector3.Cross(delta, Vector3.forward);
        var thicknessVector = perpen.normalized * (Thickness / 2f);

        var beginOrigin = BeginPoint + (delta.normalized * BeginOffset);
        var endOrigin = EndPoint - (delta.normalized * EndOffset);

        var v0 = beginOrigin + thicknessVector;
        var v1 = beginOrigin - thicknessVector;

        var v2 = endOrigin + thicknessVector;
        var v3 = endOrigin - thicknessVector;

        Gizmos.color = color;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(v0, v2);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(v1, v3);
    }
}
```

Also I tried referencing the child gameObject so I could make the RectTransform larger to enclose the total space the line would use.

Why won't my line / triangles render?

Comment: gizmos are only drown in the scene, not in the game

Answer (score 1):

You can use unity's [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SetPosition_Line : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer line;
    public GameObject TargetPoint;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        // line.useWorldSpace = false;
        // line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        Vector3[] pathPoints = { new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(10,10,10) };
        line .positionCount = 2;
        line .SetPositions(pathPoints);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // in the start enough. not need to do it un the update to just draw the line
    }
}
```

Or a more comeplex proposal is to use [GL.LINES](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html). Find adapted script from the documentation.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Draws a line from "startVertex" var to the curent mouse position.
    public Material mat;
    Vector3 startVertex;
    Vector3 mousePos;

    void Start()
    {
        startVertex = Vector3.zero;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        // Press space to update startVertex
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            startVertex = new Vector3(mousePos.x / Screen.width, mousePos.y / Screen.height, 0);
        }
    }

    void OnPostRender()
    {
        if (!mat)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Please Assign a material on the inspector");
            return;
        }
        GL.PushMatrix();
        mat.SetPass(0);
        GL.LoadOrtho();

        GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
        GL.Color(Color.red);
        //GL.Vertex(startVertex);
        //GL.Vertex(new Vector3(mousePos.x / Screen.width, mousePos.y / Screen.height, 0));
        
        GL.Vertex(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        GL.Vertex(new Vector3(0.3f, 0.3f, 0f));

        GL.Vertex(new Vector3(0.3f, 0.3f, 0f));
        GL.Vertex(new Vector3(0.3f, 0.5f, 0f));

        GL.Vertex(new Vector3(0.3f, 0.5f, 0f));
        GL.Vertex(new Vector3(0.7f, 0.5f, 0f));

        GL.End();

        GL.PopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]